# If $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, s.t. $f(x)>0$ for all $x$, prove that there exists $c >0$, s.t. $f(x) > c$ for all $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, s.t. $f(x)>0$ for all $x$, prove that there exists $c >0$, s.t. $f(x) > c$ for all x.

I am not sure how to approach this problem, I have tried proving this by using IVT but no results so far.

Comment: Apply [Weierstrass'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) to get that the functions attains its minimum at some $x_0$. At such a point the inequality $f(x_0)>0$ also holds. Take $f(x_0)>c>0$.

Comment: @YAlexandrov, thank you!

Comment: @YAlexandrov.  I'm struggling with this problem now in my Real Analysis class.  Conceptually, I get that: since $f(x)>0$ is continuous for all $x\in [a,b]$, then there is a least element $f(x_0)>0$.  Then because of Archimidean Property there exists some $c|~0<c<f(x_0)$  I don't understand how weierstrass applies.  From Text: "Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem (for sequence) A bounded sequence of real numbers has a convergent subsequence".  It seems that since continuous there would be infinitely many convergent subsequences.  Sorry if posted in wrong place.  Didn't want to start new on same prob.

Comment: I'm sure that I'm misunderstanding something....I guess my hang-up is what justification do I have to declare a minimum value $f(x_0)$ where $x_0\in [a,b]$.  I thought of Well Ordered Property but that only applies to $\mathbb{N}$ as I understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ continuous on $[a,b]$, $f$ attains its minimum , i.e there is a $m \in [a,b]$   such that $f(x)  \ge f(m) \gt 0.$

For $c:= (1/2)f(m)$ we have:

$f(x) \gt c,$ for $x\in [a,b].$